# Too many arguments for public open fun navigateUp()

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I created a new Android project in Kotlin. I also created a new Navigation Drawer Activity using the wizard. As always nothing works out of the box.

The following lines showed a compilation error:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

I had to import the method and add the first argument ‍♂:

```
import androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController
...
val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Now the next line shows a compilation error:

```
val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) // does not compile
```

Error:

```
"Too many arguments for public open fun navigateUp(): Boolean defined in androidx.navigation.NavController"
```

I have the following dependency in my gradle configuration:

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
```

It contains the `NavController.kt` file, which contains the extension function. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem but it works for me.
Check if you have proper imports

Instead of yours:

```
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
```

I have:

```
import androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController
```

And for navigateUp:

```
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
```

Comment: Yeap. I was missing the navigateUp import. Thanks!