# Too many arguments for public open fun navigateUp()

Tags: android, kotlin, uinavigationcontroller

I wrote the next code

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment)
return NavigationUI.navigateUp(drawerLayout, navController) // that line makes an error
```

After what I caught that error

```
Too many arguments for public open fun navigateUp(): Boolean defined in androidx.navigation.NavController
```

My imports connected to this block of code are

```
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
```

Gradle config

```
def nav_version = "2.5.3"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

I've tried a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762264/too-many-arguments-for-public-open-fun-navigateup), but it didn't help at all, because doing that I just got a new error

```
Unresolved reference: findNavController
```

Comment: So did you also import the [`navigateUp(AppBarConfiguration)` extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#(androidx.navigation.NavController).navigateUp(androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration))?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout)
```